# How do I put percent in a y-axis label with chart helper

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, label

I want show y-axis labels in percentage.

```
   public Series CreateSeries(DateTime dataIni, DateTime dataFim, int idLista, SeriesChartType chartType)
    {
        Series seriesDetail = new Series();
        seriesDetail.Name = "Setores";
        seriesDetail.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
        seriesDetail.IsVisibleInLegend = true;
        seriesDetail.Color = Color.FromArgb(198, 99, 99);
        seriesDetail.ChartType = chartType;
        seriesDetail.BorderWidth = 2;
        DataPoint point;

        var monitoramentos = ObterMonitoramentosProgramaSol(dataIni, dataFim, idLista);
        List<GraficoProgramaSol> dados = new List<GraficoProgramaSol>();
        foreach (var item in monitoramentos)
        {
            var comportamental = item.ListaItensVerificados.Where(w => w.Item.Subgrupo.Nome == EnumTipoSubgrupo.COMPORTAMENTAL.ToString());
            dados.Add(new GraficoProgramaSol
            {
                Setor = item.Setor.Descricao,
                NotaFinalSetor = (comportamental.Sum(s => s.Valor) + item.ListaItensVerificados.Sum(s => s.Valor)) * 100 / (comportamental.Sum(s => s.MaiorDisponivel()) + item.ListaItensVerificados.Sum(s => s.MaiorDisponivel()))
            });
            foreach (var item2 in dados.Where(i => i.Setor == item.Setor.Descricao).ToList())
            {
            point = new DataPoint();
            point.AxisLabel = item2.Setor;
            point.LabelFormat = "P";
            point.YValues = new double[] {item2.NotaFinalSetor};
            seriesDetail.Points.Add(point);
            }

        }
        seriesDetail.ChartArea = "Result Chart";
        return seriesDetail;
    }
```

I got percent with the property `LabelForma="P"` but the number arent real. I got something with this format **8.700.00%**. I want something like **81%**.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The [keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456687.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) you are looking for is not so much a **format** but an **expression**: `#PERCENT`

Here is an example that shows how to display the values and their percentage for each datapoint both on top of the point and along the x-axis. Displaying percentages along the y-axis makes not sense, though.

[image]

The code creates a column chart from scratch, including some random values. The total of the datapoints' Y-Values was 517, btw..

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chart1.Series.Clear();
    Series S = chart1.Series.Add("S1");
    S.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
    Random R = new Random(123);

    int sum = 0;
    for (int m = 1; m <= 10; m++)
    {
        int yval = R.Next(100);
        int p = S.Points.AddXY(m, yval);
        S.Points[p].Label = "#VAL \n #PERCENT";

        S.Points[p].AxisLabel = "#VAL \n #PERCENT";  // <-- !!
       sum += yval; 
    }
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = S.Points.Count;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
    button1.Text = sum + " total";
}
```

I hope you can translate it to your code.. Feel free to ask, when you run into problems!

Comment: #Val is the Y-Value of each DataPoint. #PERCENT is the point's percenatge of the whole seires' points' y-values. Note that the total sum of my example is not__ 100 but 517 (by chance..)

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know that. I have some difficulties to implent the expression `#PERCENT`in my code. I have to take percentage from 4 differents values. I have done this `(Sum(s => s.Valor) + Sum(s => s.Valor2)) * 100 / Sum(s => s.BiggestValue1()) + Sum(s => s.BiggestValue2()))` When **BiggestValue** get the biggest value at each value option that was inserted. Can u understand me? Can u help me? Sorry for my English. I'm not a fluent speaker of language. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Um, frankly, I have to admit that I don't understand. Can you upload an image of what you have and what you want to achieve? There are many free file upload services you can use and then post a link.. Also please try to update and edit your question. 'These details don't belong into comments!